How can I solve this C# compile error CS0311?
I have two class:
public class A<T> where T : B<A<T>>
{ 
    public T b;
}

public class B<T> where T : A<B<T>>
{
    public T a;
}

The two classes reference each other. I'm using Unity.
Then I got the compile error: Compiler Error CS0311
In this case, how can I solve this compile error? Thank you!

Show the full error message. Nobody memorizes error numbers and the error message contains relevant information

This seems like a dependency loop. Instead of A and B, what are reasonable names for these classes? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

You can solve this using interfaces:
public interface IA<T>
{
    T b { get; set; }
}

public interface IB<T>
{
    T a { get; set; }
}

public class A<T> : IA<T> where T : IB<A<T>>
{
    public T b { get; set; }
}

public class B<T> : IB<T> where T : IA<B<T>>
{
    public T a { get; set; }
}

The classes now only refer to the interfaces, and those do not refer to anything.

Many thanks! This answer helped me a lot!
